# class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) override delete function for multi-delete

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm using the default User class for the django authentication system.

I've overrided the delete_model function on the UserAdmin class as below to execute some stuff when deleting my user. It works fine when I go to the user on the admin page, and then click on the delete button. My problem it's when I seletect one or multiple user on the UserAdmin page, it looks like this is not the delete_model function which is called. What should I do to fix it?

```
from django.contrib import admin

#create a custom model admin which allow to search on the email field
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    #override the delete method to unset the send email to the deleted_user
    def delete_model(UserAdmin, request, obj):

        #### do something ####

        obj.delete()

#unregister the basic User, and register the new User ModelAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: You should use the `UserAdmin` from django instead of just a normal `ModelAdmin` as a base class otherwise you will lose all the other UserAdmin specific functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the solution 1 described by iklinac:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected as django_delete_selected


class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    actions = ['delete_selected']

    def delete_model(modeladmin, request, obj):
        # do something with the user instance

        obj.delete()

    def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        # do something with the users in the queryset

        return django_delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset)
    delete_selected.short_description = django_delete_selected.short_description

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting selected is done by Django function called **delete_selected**

```
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected
```

There are 2 approaches to resolve this

1. Disable original delete_selected and create your own that you will add up into admin actions
2. Override  UserModels queryset/manager delete() method

Comment: To be exact option 2 would be overriding the UserModels queryset/manager `delete()` method. But this would involve using a custom user model.